# Googe Authentication from .net Core not hitting my CallBackPtah that i have set in Startup Class

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

While working on Google Authentication from .net Core Api am facing an issue.
In .net core , After successful authentication from google, it does not hitting CallBackPath that I have set in Startup Class under the app.UseGoogleAuthentication.

If I am not setting the CallBackPath in startup class then it takes "signin-google" by default.
How can I handle this call back?
My StartUp Class-

// Adds a cookie-based authentication middleware to application

> app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
>               {
>                   LoginPath = new PathString("/account/login"),
>                   AuthenticationScheme = "MyCookieMiddlewareInstance",
>                   AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
>                   AutomaticChallenge = true,
>                   AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Home/AccessDenied"),
>
> ```
>         });
> ```

// Plugin Google Authentication configuration options

> app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOptions
>               {
>                   AuthenticationScheme = "Google",
>                  DisplayName = "Google",
>                   SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
>                   ClientId = "Google ClientId",
>                   ClientSecret = "Google ClientSecret",
>                   Scope = { "email", "openid" },
>                   AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
>                   AutomaticChallenge = true,
>                   CallbackPath = new PathString("api/values/1")
>               });

Comment: Does it hit anything? That is, are you getting a 404 on a different path?

Comment: no its not hitting any Call back path

Comment: Could the problem be with the app setup of Google since that's not redirecting to your site?